# Вопрос по XLST и атрибуте xmlns=""

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl

Мне нужно с помощью XSLT преобразовать файл xml.
Как во входящем xml документе игнорировать атрибут xmlns="" в файле xls

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <FictionBook xmlns="http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0" 
   xmlns:l="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <description>
        <title-info>
        <genre>religion_esoterics</genre>
            <author>
              <first-name>name author</first-name>
              <last-name>last name author</last-name>
            </author>
            <book-title>Book title</book-title>
            <annotation>
              sadasd
            </annotation>
        </title-info>
        <custom-info>asd</custom-info>
    </description>
</FictionBook>
```

xsl file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="FictionBook/description/custom-info"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Если у тега "FictionBook"  убрать 'xmlns="..."'  то все отрабатывает как нужно и выводится текст из custom-info

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующий XSLT.

Вам нужно объявить пространство имен по умолчанию с префиксом. И используйте его в выражениях XPath.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:FictionBook/ns1:description/ns1:custom-info"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Рад слышать, что предложенное решение работает для вас. Пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его как ответ.